# Can guard condition be a method call?

Tags: java, uml, state

I want to make a state diagram. I saw this link on wikipedia about guard conditions - [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine#Guard_conditions). Can I have a method call `(getKeyCount() == 0)` instead of a guard condition `(key_count == 0)`?

Comment: @Thihara - do i have to specifically mention the argument which causes the necessary guard condition ? eg setIsDisabledByUser(true) ?

Comment: @Thihara - where can i see examples or notes on how multiple conditions are represented ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call methods for getting a values in the if condition and evaluate it.

You can call pretty much whatever you want so long as it evaluates for a `boolean`.

What you need to set before calling the methods depends on what code you have written. I have no idea where the `setIsDisabledByUser` came from.

Multiple condition are combined in the same if statement via `&& (logical and) or || (logical or)`

There are so many examples and resources for this on the net if you will just search for it..